# java spring scheduler running multiple times in prod

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, crontrigger

I am running a web application scheduler of spring(cron) for sending notification mail, when running on local server its running fine but on production mode its sending multiple mails.

```
<bean id="EmailNotificationScheduledTask" class="com.prism.utils.EmailNotificationTask" />
    <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="EmailNotificationScheduledTask" method="run" cron="0 0 10 * * MON"/> 
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="1"/>
    
</beans>
```

```
public class EmailNotificationTask extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                sendPropertyNotificationEmail();
            }
        //}
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void sendPropertyNotificationEmail(){
        try{
            //Mail sending logic
        }
            
        } catch (DAOException ee) {
            _logger.error("Error while sending notification messages", ee);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any annotations in your code, too?

Comment: @hisener no just the "sendPropertyNotificationEmail" method is being called, which contains the mail sending functionality

Comment: Is sendPropertyNotificationEmail() expected to send one mail per invocation? When you say 'sending multiple mails', do you mean that somehow sendPropertyNotificationEmail() is invoked in multiple threads? Please clarify more on the problem.

Comment: @Rahul yes i think it is getting invoked in multiple threads. Yes the function is implemented to send one mail every monday at 10 am, when m testing it locally it is running fine, only one mail is getting sent but when deployed in the production mode, multiple mails are being sent

Comment: @Rahul, hisener please find the original code in the question i have edited it again. Actually in original code run method is called.

Comment: I think you do not need override of the run method. Spring handles that. Please refer https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: @hisener ok but still its behaving the same.

Comment: @hisener  and also how can you say that run method is generating the issue? please explain.

Comment: I thought somehow run method executed as well as sendPropertyNotificationEmail. I am not quite sure what problem is. I need to try but I am not available right now, sorry.

Comment: Are there more than one servers running in production?

Answer (score 0):

Check how instances are configured on your production container. Turn off auto-scaling, if it is set. A batch program should never have more than one instance running at any given point.